# Enabling and Disabling cbomboBox in VB.net with modules

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I am trying to enable and disable two combo boxes depending on a selection.

```
Public Function itemsEnabled(item, item2)
    Dim cboCate As String
    Dim cboItemM = frmStore.cboItem
    Dim cboItemM2 = frmStore.cboItem2
    cboCate = frmStore.cboCategory.SelectedItem
    cboItemM = frmStore.cboItem
    cboItemM2 = frmStore.cboItem2
    Try
        If cboCate = "Coffee" Then
            cboItemM.Enabled = True
            cboItemM2.Enabled = False
            'if coffee is chosen then colddrink combo box is disabled
        ElseIf cboCate = "ColdDrink" Then
            cboItemM2.Enabled = True
            cboItemM.Enabled = False
            'if colddrink is chosen then coffe combo box is disable
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    End Try
    Return cboItemM
End Function'
```

And when I select an option in the `cboCate` (category) nothing happens, I tried adding `ToString()` at the end of line 5 but I get the error:

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Can't you compare the `SelectedValue` property of the combobox?. And most importantly, are you executing this function inside the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the combobox?

Comment: @DCruz22 I've tried doing that as well with no luck, and yes I am - Module1.itemsEnabled(cboItem, cboItem1)

Comment: Are you sure something is selected in the combo? Suggest you switch Option Explicit on and fix all those issues too.

Comment: @ZhemeArts have you debugged the application?

Comment: Is `frmStore` the name of the Class or form instance?

Comment: @Plutonix It's the name of the form

Comment: @DCruz22 'cboCate', 'cboItemM', 'cboItemM1' all have the value of nothing.

Comment: @ZhemeArts make sure you're matching the names of the controls.

Comment: does it say `Public Class frmStore` at the top?  If so, the answer is "it is the class name" in which case you are using default form instances, and the reason is that there are no items in the class.

Comment: @Plutonix Yeah it does say `Public Class frmStore` and I didn't understand your last part